# Acl node.js module

Tags: node.js, express, acl

I'm trying to use [acl module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/acl) for user permissions.

I've installed the module with `npm install acl --save`.

Added these lines to code:

```
var acl = require('acl');
var redisClient = require('redis');

acl = new acl(new acl.redisBackend(redisClient, 'session'));

acl.allow('member', 'events', 'view');
```

Received this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'multi'
    at Object.RedisBackend.begin (workspace/server/node_modules/acl/lib/redis-backend.js:23:23)
    at Acl.allow (workspace/server/node_modules/acl/lib/acl.js:231:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (workspace/server/app.js:24:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object..js (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-dev/lib/hook.js:52:17)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the redisClient was not properly initialized.

```
//this line did the trick
var redisInstance = require('redis').createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1', {no_ready_check: true});
```

and then

```
acl = new acl(new acl.redisBackend(redisInstance, 'session'));
```